# How to Hide specific UIButtons based on String contained in Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have some UIButtons that represents different Restaurants the content comes from a struct. In this struct is an Array with Tags for each Restaurant.
How can I hide a UIButton based on the  Tags?
At the moment I have this in an provisionally way:

```
func filterFavorites() {
    if importedDataA.filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService) {
        isVisibleA = true
    } else {
        isVisibleA = false
    }
    if importedDataB.filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService) {
        isVisibleB = true
    } else {
        isVisibleB = false
    }
    if importedDataC.filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService) {
        isVisibleC = true
    } else {
        isVisibleC = false
    }
    if importedDataD.filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService) {
        isVisibleD = true
    } else {
        isVisibleD = false
    }
    if importedDataE.filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService) {
        isVisibleE = true
    } else {
        isVisibleE = false
    }
    if importedDataF.filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService) {
        isVisibleF = true
    } else {
        isVisibleF = false
    }
    if importedDataG.filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService) {
        isVisibleG = true
    } else {
        isVisibleG = false
    }
```

etc...

And...

```
func filterApply() {
    if isVisibleA == true {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hideFilteredObjects") == true {
            cellA.isHidden = false
        } else {
            //cellA.popIn()
        }
    } else {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hideFilteredObjects") == true {
            cellA.isHidden = true
        } else {
            //cellA.popOut()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you build a dictionary of tags and buttons, so for every tag you might have a list of buttons which are either shown or hidden (based on you desired operations), then you could simply loop through the list of buttons and applied that desired action

Comment: use `isVisibleA = importedDataA.filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService)` instead of the if else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating several instances of your struct importedDataA, importedDataB, importedDataC, etc., you can just create an array of instances something like:

```
var importedData: [your-structure] = []
```

Then instead of going through all of these items one by one with an if statement, you can use a for loop to go through these instances like:

```
for data in importedData{
  if data.filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService){
    isVisibleG = true
  } else {
    isVisibleG = false
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a struct:

```
struct ImportedData{
    var filterTags: [Int]
}

 let buttons = [UIButton]() // add your buttons

 let importedData = [ImportedData]() // add your importedData

 (0..<(buttons.count)).map{buttons[$0].isHidden =     UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hideFilteredObjects") && (!importedData[$0].filterTags.contains(filterPresetRestaurantTypeService))}
```